# Getting the domain from a URL encoded string

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Another beginner question, I'm afraid...

I was wondering if someone could tell me the easiest and most efficient way of getting the fully qualified domain name (e.g. *www.google.com*) from a `UrlEncoded` string in ASP.Net (C#).

For example:

```
 http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dsome%20things%20i%20searched%20for
```

Would give me:

```
 www.google.com
```

(Or basically anything where I can check the domain to make sure it's correct.)

I'm guessing the first step might be to `UrlDecode`, but since this is how I'm getting the string, I thought I'd mention it incase it's easier Encoded.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(new URI(System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode(url))).Host
```

For reference:

URI - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

HttpServerUtility - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Comment: Every now and then I type new Url( xxx ) and get surprised it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Request.Url.host to get the hostname.